# Use dict to define Snakemake one input, multiple outputs

Tags: python, dictionary, snakemake

I have a dictionary that maps file names to sample names to barcodes:

```
dict = {'file_1': {'sample1': 'barcode1', 'sample2': 'barcode2'}}
```

I need to use Snakemake to read this dict, and use the keys/values as inputs and outputs.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
Input:
   file_1.fastq.gz
Output:
   o1 = barcode1.fastq.gz, 
   o2 = barcode2.fastq.gz,
Shell:
   """
   do something with {input} barcode1 barcode2
   """
```

I've given some structure to how I've been attempting this, but I haven't been successful.

```
#get list of fq names based on multiplex name
def get_fq_names(wildcards):
    fq = dict[wildcards.filename]
    return(fq)

#create demux command line
def demux_cmd(wildcards):
    cmd_line = multiplex_dict[wildcards.filename] + [LIST OF BARCODES]
    return(cmd_line)

#rule to perform demux
rule demultiplex:
    input:
        f1 = get_fq_names
    params:
        cmd = demux_cmd,
    output:
        [list barcode1.fastq.gz, barcode2.fastq.gz]
    shell:
        """
        {params.cmd}
        """
```

THANK YOU!

```
#re-written to hopefully help clarify.
```

Comment: It is not very clear to me (among other things) what the output of your rule should be and how the `mp` wildcard is supposed to be determined. You should probably try to clarify this in your question.

Comment: I've updated for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the prototype you added, your output will consist in two files, containing barcodes in their names.

I don't get why in your implementation attempt you have this strange syntax:

```
output:
    [list barcode1.fastq.gz, barcode2.fastq.gz]
```

You should probably simply do like in your "prototype", but using the barcodes as wildcards (note the curly braces and the quotes):

```
output:
    o1 = "{barcode1}.fastq.gz", 
    o2 = "{barcode2}.fastq.gz",
```

(It is not an issue if you don't use `output.o1` and `output.o2` in your `run` section, as long as you are certain that the command will generate files with the desired names given the barcodes.)

Wildcard values will be determined based on matching final desired files (*) with a rule's output file patterns. It is important to understand that: **wildcards are determined from output file names**. Therfore, you will not have a wildcard for the "filename". You will have to somehow use these "barcode" wildcards in an input function and your dictionary to determine the corresponding input filename.

Assuming the dictionary going from filename to barcodes defined in your snakefile:

```
filename2samples = {'file_1': {'sample1': 'barcode1', 'sample2': 'barcode2'}}
```

Your input function could "reverse" the lookup in the dictionary using a loop until the barcodes in the wildcards are found, as follows:

```
def get_fq_names(wildcards):
    for (filename, sample2bc) in filename2samples.items():
        if sample2bc["sample1"] == wildcards.barcode1 and sample2bc["sample2"] == wildcards.barcode2:
            # (f-string syntax requires python 3.6 or above)
            return f"{filename}.fastq.gz"
```

A similar approach could be used to build the command.

(*) You will also need a "driving" rule having as input the names of the final desired files. You should place this rule before others in your snakefile:

```
rule all:
    input:
        [
            f"{bc}.fastq.gz" for bc in sample2bc.values()
            for sample2bc in filename2samples.values()]
```

(Not tested)